# MongoDB getting unique set of words from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Let's say I have a few collections in MongoDB that I would like to get an intersection of the words for example.

```
                    fruit db
      fresh fruit        |      dried fruit       |
-------------------------|-------------------------
{ "type": "apple" }           { type: "apple" } 
{ "type": "orange" }          { type: "peach" }
{ "type": "peach" }           { type: "pineapple" }
{ "type": "pear" }            { type: "grape" }
{ "type": "watermelon" }      { type: "mango" }
{ "type": "grape" }           { type: "plum"  }
```

as you can see from the above example, there's fresh and dried fruits but there are similar items between each collection. There could also be more than just two collections.

How could I run some query on this database to say find all the same type of fruit from each collection.

since apple, peach, and grape are in both collections, is there a way to extract data like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) command for this. To find common fruits in "freshFruit" and "driedFruit" collections a query like the following can be used:

```
db.freshFruit.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "driedFruit",
            localField: "type",
            foreignField: "type",
            as: "fruit"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "fruit": { $ne: [] } }
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`
db.freshFruit.aggregate([
        {
        $lookup: {
            from: "driedFruit",
            localField: "type",
            foreignField: "type",
            as: "fruit"
                  }
       },
       {$match: { "fruit": { $ne: [] } }},
       //Add another lookup and match to join another collection and at last use             $ group stage
        { $group: { "_id": null,fruits : {$push :$type}}}
]);
```

`
In fruits you will get all fruit that exists in all collection